# How can an Azure/hybrid joined device identity be used to authenticate to an Azure protected API?

Tags: c#, powershell, azure-active-directory

We have a service/scheduled job that will run on Azure joined and/or Hybrid joined Windows and Macs. We want that service to call an API using the device's own identity (not an end-user identity, but the device itself).

This is parallel to the traditional domain joined model where a service running on a workstation could use machine's persona (NetworkService) to connect to a web service, database, etc.

The documented device registration flow [1] returns device specific certificates (associated with the locally generated private key), but I cannot find any documentation or library methods that explain how to use that key/cert to get an access/id token for use with an API. Should the authn request be similarly constructed to an application authentication certificate credential [2]?

Primary Refresh Tokens (PRTs) are tied to a device, but they seem to be user specific, so not an option for us.

Essentially, a DeviceAuthenticationWithX509Certificate[3] for "workstations" and not IOT devices.

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/device-registration-how-it-works
[2] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/certificate-credentials
[3] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.client.deviceauthenticationwithx509certificate?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 0):

You could create a User Principal to represent that machine, ensure through conditional access that it could only ever authenticate from that machine, and require it to use cert based auth for authentication. But that would actually be the 5th most desirable approach based on the flowchart below that my team developed during my time at Microsoft:

1. Does service support managed identities? -> Use Managed Service Identities
2. Does service support workload identities -> Use Workload Identity Federation
3. Does service support cert-based-auth -> Use service principal + Cert + KeyVault
4. Does service support service principal + secret -> Use SP + secret + KeyVault
5. Otherwise, use a User Principal

What do you think?

Comment: In AAD (now Entra) every device (Windows/Mac) is already a principal in the directory. We have 100K such devices and creating a user principal for each and managing those credentials seems like a waste when the device already has a principal. It just seems MS has hid the documentation to utilize it. Much like a client_credentials with jwt bearer grant_type, it seems like there must be a device_credentials type (not to be confused with a device code flow) or similar flow with jwt-bearer.

Comment: Interesting. I know that it took a long time to get Conditional Access and Logging support for Service Principal authentication so there might be work required to support device-without-user-or-service-principal authentication. Could the same objective be achieved if the API was registered with an application ID, took the device ID as a parameter, and used conditional access to ensure it could only be accessed from compliant devices? I will follow the question to see if anyone knows a way to achieve what you are looking for.